# Cannot give Google CDN service account to Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, google-cloud-cdn

I am trying to give the Google CDN service account access to my bucket as said here: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls

`gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:service-{PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloud-cdn-fill.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer gs://{BUCKET}`

But the response is:
`BadRequestException: 400 Invalid argument`

Adding it via the cloud console is also impossible, it says "Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account or Google Apps account."

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud CDN cache fill service account is created when you enable signed URLs. The error message suggests there's a problem with the project number or you haven't yet enabled signed URLs for that project. You can enable signed URLs by following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#creatingkeys. Make sure you enable signed URLs for a backend service or backend bucket in the same project you specify in the gsutil command.

Comment: I thought I already created a signed URL key but apparently I missed the last of the three "save" buttons I have to press in a row. Still, my bad. Maybe some clarification about the service account in the docs would help.

Comment: I get the message "No changes made to gs://[bucket].  And I still get the alert of no permissions given. If I go to IAM i find no service with name cloud-cdn-fill.iam. Do I have to create it manually?

Comment: htafoya, "No changes made" suggests you've already given the account access. You shouldn't see the account listed in IAM because it is Cloud CDN's account, not yours. Where do you see a no permissions given alert, and what exactly does the alert say?